# Checking run of heads to the end of vector

Tags: r

I wrote the R function, which computes the length of the run of heads. It is working almost well but it is not considering the last run. For example when I have run like that

```
> "T" "T" "T" "H" "T" "H" "H" "T" "T" "T" "T" "H" "H" "T" "T" "T" "T" "H" "T" "T"
```

this code (m is my run of heads as above):

```
counts=c()
counter=1
for (i in 2:(length(m))){
  if (m[i]==m[i-1]){
    counter=counter+1
  }
  else {
    counts<-append(counts,counter)
    counter=1
  }
}
counts
```

is returning:

```
> [1] 3 1 1 2 4 2 4 1
```

instead of:

```
> [1] 3 1 1 2 4 2 4 1 2
```

How can I update my code to consider this last run? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need `rle(m)$lengths`

Comment: Unfortunately I have to do it without using rle function ;)

Comment: It is because the last evaluation is not done.  it is getting the `counter <-1` from the `else`

Comment: @akrun I moved line which is appending value to counts vector from else to if but it is working completely bad now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but the last value remains in the variable `counter` and is not appended to `counts`. After the loop is over you can add that value in the vector.

```
m <- c("T", "T", "T", "H", "T", "H", "H", "T", "T" ,"T", "T" ,"H", "H", "T" ,"T", "T", "T", "H", "T" ,"T")
counts=c()
counter=1

for (i in 2:(length(m))){
  if (m[i]==m[i-1]){
    counter=counter+1
  }
  else {
    counts<-append(counts,counter)
    counter=1
  }
}
counts <- append(counts, counter)
counts
#[1] 3 1 1 2 4 2 4 1 2
```